# Build policy using TeamCity with TFS

Tags: git, teamcity

TFS or Visual Studio Team Services has the possibility to define a branch policy on Git repositories, so that pull requests are required to have a successful build before they can be merged.

Is there any way to implement a similar policy while using TeamCity as build server? It seems like the policy is directly linked to a TFS build definition ID and therefore cannot be used with other build systems and also wasn't able to find an API which can be called to set the build state of a PR.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly associate to a team city build.

You can however create an indirect association by creating a Team Build Definition that kicks off the Team City build (or just waits for it's result) and then using that.

Create an empty build definition and add a single PowerShell task and add some inline PowerShell that does the check.